# How to check if a Tab is already removed in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Under MainActivity this is how I am adding TABS

```
        tab1 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 1");
        tabLayout.addTab(tab1);

        tab2 = (tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tab2);
```

So, from Dialog box basically I have implemented my program to add & removed tab but my problem is I can't find a way to check if the tab is already removed hence, my program runs into errors if the tabs are already removed previously

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null)
    return;
   settingList = (ArrayList < SettingCheckBox > ) data.getSerializableExtra(SETTING_CHECK_BOX);
   for (int i = 0; i < settingList.size(); i++) {
    if (settingList.get(i).getChecked()) {
     Log.d("**Checked Item**", String.valueOf(settingList.get(i).getDescription()));
     //gets the description of the tab that is to be removed
     String removeTab = String.valueOf(settingList.get(i).getDescription());
     //gets the value of the check box                                
     Boolean checkedValue = settingList.get(i).getChecked();


     if (removeTab.equals("TAB 1")) {
      //How to check if Tab is already removed ? 
      if (checkedvalue)
       if (tabLayout.equals(tab1)) {
        tabLayout.removeTab(tab1);
        //basically removes fragment associated with the tab
        pagerAdapter.removeTab(0, tab1);
       }
     }

    } else if (removeTab.equals("TAB 2")) {
     if (checkedValue) {
      tabLayout.removeTab(tab2);
      pagerAdapter.removeTab(1, tab2);

     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this in my app:

```
public boolean isMatching(final String tabString){
    boolean match=false;
    for(int i=0;i<tablayout.getTabCount();i++){
        if(tablayout.getTabAt(i).getText().toString().equals(tabString)){
            match=true;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

Then using :

```
if(isMatching(yourstring)){
    //you didnt removed it,
    // there is at least one tab that equals your string
}else{
    //there is no tab that matches your string
}
```

Can you try like and come again ?

Comment: yes working. thanx. Btw do u know of any source where I can learn more about this ?

Comment: @choman yes, for material guidelines checkout this site : [Tab Layout Guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs)   , For learning about tablayout , parameters , functions etc : [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) . Also you can look for codepaths guide : [Codepath Tablayout](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout)

Comment: Thank you very much Yasin. :)